# Javascript - regex to validate character in specific positions

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate characters at multiple position using regex

The source string can be `6-4,4-6,6-4`

Want to validate below

1. `the char at position 0 should be [1-7]`
2. `the char at position 1 should be [-]`
3. `the char at position 2 should be [1-7]`
4. `the char at position 3 should be [,]`
5. `the char at position 4 should be [1-7]`
6. `the char at position 5 should be [-]`
7. `the char at position 6 should be [1-7]`
8. `the char at position 7 should be [,]`
9. `the char at position 8 should be [1-7]`
10. `the char at position 9 should be [-]`
11. `the char at position 10 should be [1-7]`

Should return true if above matches else false

Let me know how i can enhance below to validate multiple position and good reference for javascript regex

```
new RegExp("^.{0}[1-7]").test("6-4,4-4,6-4")
```

Comment: and what are the cases which should fail ? is [`^(?:[1-7]-[1-7],)*?(?:[1-7]-[1-7],?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/W8lnEE/1/) what you're after ?

Comment: `var regex = /^[1-7]-[1-7](?:,[1-7]-[1-7])*$/`?

Comment: if - or , is missing at specific position or the number is is not between 1-7

Comment: @upog `6-4,6-4` this doesn't have a trailing `,` should it match ?

Comment: @Code Maniac yes. the source can be either 7 or 11 characters and it will not have , at the end. I can have separate regex for different length. if it works for any one i'm fine

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew its returning false expecting true here new RegExp(" /^[1-7]-[1-7](?:,[1-7]-[1-7])*$/").test("6-4,6-1")

Comment: @upog please update the question with proper rules. it make easy and accurate answer to be produced else it's just a guess work

Comment: I suggested `var regex = /^[1-7]-[1-7](?:,[1-7]-[1-7])*$/` and **NOT** `var regex = new RegExp(" /^[1-7]-[1-7](?:,[1-7]-[1-7])*$/")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the source can be either 7 or 11 characters and it will not have , at
>   the end. [`specified by op`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156976/javascript-regex-to-validate-character-in-specific-positions/58157079#comment102696628_58156976)

You can use

```
^(?:[1-7]-[1-7],){1,2}(?:[1-7]-[1-7])$
```

[image]

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/W8lnEE/3/)

```js
const regex = /^(?:[1-7]-[1-7],){1,2}(?:[1-7]-[1-7])$/;
const strs = ['6-4,4-6,6-4', '6-4,6-4', '9-2', '123-1231', '1232', '123#1221', '1-2', '1-2,1-2,1-2,']

strs.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str, ' | ', regex.test(str))
})
```

Comment: yes, i updated to make question simple and clear. actually it can be 7 or 11.

Comment: @upog i did handled it in answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: perfect, Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you don't want to let pass `1-1,` or `,1-1` I would try something like

```
^(?:[1-7]-[1-7],?\b)+$
```

[See this demo at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/b6KWhE/1)

- `,?` [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) comma for quantifying the group
- `\b` matches a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (ensures there is a comma between each eg `1-1`)

Matches one or more `1-1`. If you want to match 2 up to 3, [use `{2,3}` instead of of `+` at end](https://regex101.com/r/b6KWhE/3).